# Apple TV AirPlay and Ethernet

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay, ethernet, mirroring

Ok, not a techie.  I have an iPad (2018) connected via Ethernet cable, I am planning to get an Apple TV (also connected via Ethernet).  Will I be able to connect thru AirPlay to ATV, and cast to my TV, thru my IPad (and modem/network)???  Not keen on Wifi anymore so want to mostly use Ethernet.  thanks!

Comment: How/with what do you connect your iPad via Ethernet? And where will the Ethernet cable from you iPad and your TV get plugged into on the „other“ end?

Comment: A network is a network, wether the medium is wire or radio. That said it *should* work but it is an unusual configuration and nothing I have ever heard of before.

Comment: Are you connecting your iPad with a method [like this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7794507)?

Comment: It doesn’t matter for this question how it is connected - they all work the same way for AirPlay. Doesn’t matter if you use the Apple Camera Adapter and a USB-Ethernet dongle, if you use a Lightning-Ethernet adapter, or you use one of the new iPad Pros and a USB-C Ethernet dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works without problems. I have used such a setup myself.

Note both devices should be connected to the same local network. It doesn’t work remote over the Internet without special VPN.

Comment: Jksoegaard, thanks!  Yes, I connected my ipad to thru Ethernet with a lightning to USB camera dongle (with power), and then to a USB-Ethernet dongle.  Works fine.  Both devices will be connected on the same network - have no idea at this point (haven’t purchased ATV yet) how to connect thru airplay but will follow my nose and see how I go!!

Comment: There’s nothing special to do - works exactly like on WiFi!